# How to update and persist entity after the entity manager was closed due to an exception and then re-opend?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, entitymanager

I am working on a Symfony + Doctrine based project. When an exception occurs during a long running import operation (parsing data, creating entities, persisting them, etc.) the **entity manager is closed**.

Also I tried to re-open the entity manager I cannot use it properly and I get `EntityNotFoundException` or `ORMInvalidArgumentException` when trying to persist other entities.

**So: How to properly re-open a closed entity manager to be able to use it again?**

---

**Details:**

- To avoid that other user actions conflict with a running import, the user account is locked before the import starts.
- This is done by querying an `ImportLock` entity for the current user from the DB. If no such lock exists a new entity is created. The lock is set to active and persisted. If an active lock already exists, another import is active and the current import is not started.
- A `transaction` is started to handle the import
- Import data is parsed, entities are created and persisted
- If everything is fine, the transaction is committed and the lock is set to inactive. Done.
- However, when data is imported which already exists, a `UniqueConstraintViolationException` is thrown which **closes the entity manager**.
- Although the exception is caught and the entity is reset, it is not possible to update the lock entity.

Code:

```
$lockRepo = $this->entityManager->getRepository(ImportLock::class);
$lock = $lockRepo->findOneByUser($user);

if (!$lock) {
    $lock = new ImportLock();
}

if ($lock->isActive()) {
    // Import already running --> cancel
    return;
}

$lock->setActive();
$this->entityManager->persist($lock);
$this->entityManager->flush();


// Import
try {
    $this->entityManager->getConnection()->beginTransaction();
    doImport();
    $this->entityManager->getConnection()->commit();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $this->entityManager->getConnection()->rollback();

    if (!$this->entityManager->isOpen()) {
        // Step 1
        $this->doctrineRegistry->resetManager();

        // Step 2
        $lockRepo = $this->entityManager->getRepository(ImportLock::class);
        $lock = $lockRepo->findOneById($lock->getId()); // look up entity using Id to avoid using the $user which was handled by the "old" entity manager
    }
} finally {
    $lock->setInactive();
    $this->entityManager->persist($lock);  // <-- Exception
    $this->entityManager->flush();
}
```

Depending on what I try, I get different exceptions when trying to persist the lock:

- `Doctrine\ORM\Exception\EntityManagerClosed` when the the entity manager is not re-opend / reset (Step1 and Step2 NOT performed)
- `Doctrine\\ORM\\EntityNotFoundException(code: 0): Unable to find "My\\Entity\\User\" entity identifier associated with the UnitOfWork` when `$lock` is not reloaded after resetting the entity manager (Step2 NOT performed)
- `Doctrine\\ORM\\ORMInvalidArgumentException(code: 0): A new entity was found through the relationship 'My\\Entity\\ImportLock#user' that was not configured to cascade persist operations for entity: My\\Entity\\User@621` when entity manger is reset and `$lock` is reloaded (both Step1 and Step2 performed).

It seems that somehow the `$lock` which was queried/created using the "old" entity manager cannot properly be used with the "new" (re-opend) entity manager.

**How to solve this?**

Comment: Have you tried setting the transaction explicitly and in case of an exception, in addition to rolling back you also unlock the record!?

Comment: Is this code executed inside a service (such as a command) or a controller?